# Error: no such file or directory in React Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, react-server

I trying to do server side rendering on my existing react project but having problem.

I think the problem is memory-fs is unable to find file or directory. I have read many threads but no luck as of yet.

Below is the error

```
/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:114
            throw new MemoryFileSystemError(errors.code.ENOENT, _path);
            ^
Error: no such file or directory
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFileSync (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:114:10)
    at serverCompiler.run (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/server.js:34:25)
    at emitRecords.err (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at next (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:190:13)
    at next (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:190:13)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:365:9)
    at require.forEach.err (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:354:15)
    at /var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1050:13)
    at /var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
    at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9)
    at writeOut (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:343:28)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/var/www/nodejs/rivigo_main/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:288:4)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple way to reproduce your bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should not access `devMiddleware.fileSystem`. It's private. Instead rewrite requests.